# Two factor authentication for password login but not for login using keys files

Tags: ssh, pam, pki, two-factor-authentication

I configured ssh to using keys files situated in `~/.ssh` to login. Now I'd like to install a two factor authentication when using password, but not required when using key files. I've seen how to install two factor authentication here: [DigitalOcean: How To Protect SSH With Two-Factor Authentication](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-two-factor-authentication).

But it applies for both keys logins and password login, I'd like to use it only for password login.

I'd like:

- public-key -> ok to enter server

or

- password -> one-time password -> ok to enter server

Maybe it is possible to do something with the `AuthenticationMethods` in `sshd_config`? I've found this: [OpenSSH use (public key or password) + google authenticator](https://serverfault.com/questions/753530/openssh-use-public-key-or-password-google-authenticator)

Comment: When you set it up according to the linked article, how does it work?

Answer (score 2):

AuthenticationMethods accepts multiple choices. AND operations use a comma, OR operations use spaces. So the example at the link you had above was:

`AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive:pam password,keyboard-interactive:pam`

This says to allow either a key and challenge-response, or a password and challenge-response. This will do what you're requesting.

I do highly advise that you limit key authentication to known hosts using `Match` blocks as shown at https://blog.tinned-software.net/restrict-ssh-logins-using-ssh-keys-to-a-particular-ip-address/

Answer (score 1):

That's how it works by default.

By default, the `auth` stack of PAM is not consulted by sshd when key based authentication is in use. The other stacks will still fire (i.e. `account` will still enforce your access policies), but it requires additional configuration (customizing `AuthenticationMethods`) to even end up in a situation where PAM and non-PAM authentication methods are mixed.